# getting java.lang.ClassCastException: com.app.LoginInfo cannot be cast to com.app.LoginInfo during jboss migration

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

We are migrating our server from `Jboss 5` to `Wildfly 9`.
During migration, one of the issue which we are unable to solve is this `classcastexception`. Its happening while logging to the system. Issue is occurring inconsistently and mostly occurring after a restart.

We are getting this exception while querying using Hibernate hql and castin

```
LoginInfo userInfo = (LoginInfo) session.createQuery(hql).uniqueResult();
```

I have reconfirmed that we have only one version of `hibernate jar`.

Comment: Check the [JBoss Windup migration tool](https://github.com/windup/windup/wiki).

Answer (score 0):

Classes are not compatible if they are loaded by different class loaders. Even though you might only have a single copy of a JAR file on disk it might still be loaded by different class loaders whose classes would not be compatible.

If you are fiddling around with class loaders yourself you have to make sure that you set the parent class loader correctly to avoid situations like these.